# How to Convert Recorded Call Voice in text.?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I want to develop an application which records the call voice and convert that voice in text and show in application.

I have done till recording the call and saved in internal storage. **But now question is how to convert that into text.** Please anyone help me to solve it.

I have referred this [link](http://cozycodes.com/index.php/android-call-recorder-source-code/) to record the call and save to internal storage.

Comment: you'll need machine learning knowledge to write such functionality. Check out [Sphinx](https://cmusphinx.github.io/) which might help you with that.

Comment: Currently Android only supports RecognizerIntent, but you can Check this blog , https://mikepultz.com/2011/03/accessing-google-speech-api-chrome-11/

Comment: you mean after learning machine, that functionality has to be integrated in android.? @SamuelKok

Comment: it's [machine learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_learning). Do read up and understand what you're getting into.

Comment: The answer I am looking in android programming. not in some machine learning language. Thanks for your time @Samuel Kok